# VegaLite 2D charts to 3D conversion is possible?

Tags: vega-lite, vega, vega-lite-api

I want 3d chart of my previous vegaLite chart, but i dont know how to convert vegalite chart into 3d view. Is there any plugin or engine that convert vega/vegalite charts into 3d view chart.
I find related to this
https://observablehq.com/@mathiastiberghien/how-to-create-a-3d-engine-from-scratch-using-vega
but i want something like i just provide vegalite specs/compiled specs and that give me its 3D charts of the same.

something like-https://microsoft.github.io/SandDance/tests/v4/umd/transition.html

Special for Grouped Bar Charts i need 3d view

Davide can u help me please.

Comment: Quaternions are way out of my comfort zone I'm afraid.

Comment: can SandDance use my vega specs and give 3d view

Comment: There is a discussion about Vega 3D here with some examples.
https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/1738